# SCCM for mobile device management returns 404 on /devicemgmt/server.resource

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sccm, system-center

We have a new Windows Server 2008 R2 machine onto which we have installed SCCM SP2 followed by the R2 package.

We have enabled a mobile device management point and enabled distribution points to support mobile devices as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680634.aspx

We have also installed the Mobile Device Management Client on to a Windows Mobile 6.1 device. The client on the device fails to connect to the server. Our investigation so far has led us to the URL /devicemgmt/server.resource. However, looking in IIS on the server shows no such URL (in fact nothing apart from the aspnet_client directory) and visiting the URL with a browser returns 404.

WebDav is enabled on the Default Web Site in IIS. BITS is installed on the server.

Can anyone confirm whether enabling mobile device management will add visible directories to IIS and if so why it might be failing in our case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that WebDAV wasn't configured correctly. We found this out by looking under "System Center Configuration Manager > Site Database > System Status > Site Status > Our site > Component Status" and looking at the error messages there. Helpfully the error message explains exactly what you need to do to configure WebDAV correctly.